# join two similar spread sheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I run reports for my company and the format goes something like:

```
ID number | Title | Status | % win
```

Things come in and out of the system if we win or lose something for example it doesn't continue to show up.

Likewise new opportunities come up and add new entries to the system.

Lastly we could decide that we just don't want to do the job (no bid) and move on with our lives.

The spreadsheet I've been manually producing goes something more like:

```
ID | Title | Status| Date | Date | date ..............
```

where date is the %win from report for that date 4/13/17 or 4/1/17 etc etc etc

Right now I manually place each one by having the data side by side  but the list is growing and I would like an easier way to "Join" them

Ideas?

edit

sorry for being vague  hopefully this helps

day 1 might have

```
ID 
1  15%
2  15%
3  29%
4  55%
5  99%
```

Day 2 might have

```
ID

3  15%
4  75%
5  75%
6  15%
9  35%
```

what I would like to magically happen is

```
ID  day1  day2
1   15%    
2  15%
3  29%   15%
4  55%   75%
5  99%
6  _     15%
9  -     35%
```

Comment: You could just copy and paste them each day instead of manually typing.. Put =today() in the date column, drag down, copy, and paste back in as values only

Comment: What is the formula you used for the winrate? We might be able to suggest a version that can be autofilled to the right

Comment: It's calculated externally to excel

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague as asked, so I'll give you a few solutions. Pick your answer à la carte.

1. Rather than type today's date, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to insert today's date.
2. Vlookup is your friend. Just create a vlookup formula for each of the important columns you want to bring over and run the formulas down. I would create a merge template workbook that has the vookup formulas ready to go. Then you can just copy and paste values into the sheets referenced by the vlookups and get a sheet with the output. Paste values wherever, sort to your heart's content.
3. For optimal performance you might dabble at a VBA macro that would do this for you.

Comment: Sorry upon further review it is vague I will try to add more actual examples later if possible

Comment: I edited my original I hope that helps clarify